# Sort order on the collections page in shopify

Tags: sorting, collections, shopify

I am trying to sort the collections page, not the products in each collection. I have two collections, black and grey, and right now they're sorted alphabetically in ascending order.

Can I set the order to be descending or do I need to use a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Shopify docs for [list-collections.liquid](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-development/templates/list-collections-liquid):

> **Re-ordering the collections**
>
> When you loop through the collections array, the collections will be
>   output in alphabetical order by default.
>
> There may be instances where you want to re-order the collections
>   listed or pick and choose which collections to display. In such cases,
>   you can load the collections from a link list instead: see [Taking
>   control of the collections listing
>   page](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/taking-control-of-collections-listing)
>   for more information.

**EDIT:**

[Taking control of the collections listing page](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/taking-control-of-collections-listing):

> ...if you want your collections to be listed in a
>   particular order (say, alphabetical), and you want better control over
>   what collections are listed, use this code:
>   http://gist.github.com/523455. That code snippet will not iterate over
>   all collections in your shop. It will use the collections you will
>   have listed in a link list. **You will create a link list called
>   "Featured Collections"** on the Navigation page in your admin and you
>   will add to it only the collections that you want **and order those
>   collections as you wish them to appear.**

But if all you want to do is reverse the order, you can use the [`reversed`](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/collection-liquid-reverse-order-21329#comment-21341) keyword. For example:

```
{% for collection in collections reversed %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I read that, but it doesn't say how it can be changed from alphabetically ascending to descending. It doesn't show any other way of sorting through the collections.

Comment: Thank you. Works great. I haven't seen this in the documentation.